# Xcode is not detecting library..Cannot find Firebase 'FaceDetectorOptions' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to use Firebase FaceDetector in my app but I am keep getting error = "Cannot find 'FaceDetectorOptions' in scope" ,seems like Xcode not able to detect FireBase "GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection" library even if I do Clean build Folder my app , restarting an app and updating my PodFile.....still I am getting this error

Here my Podfile

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'
pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'

end
```

here's my Xcode code

```
  import Firebase

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
     let options = FaceDetectorOptions()     //ERROR : Cannot find 'FaceDetectorOptions' in scope
    }
```

Here's the link for google MLKIT  :
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
import MLKit
```

to the top of the file

Comment: how i suppose to know that if it is not included in documentation OR how you come to know that

Comment: Experience, if you look at the breadcrumbs at the top of the site you linked you will see MLKit. Also, in the sample code.